# Why am I unable to download the newest betas for Xcode and iOS?

Tags: xcode, iphone-developer-program

When I go to the iOS developer center, having logged in and everything, it just lists the non-developer versions of iOS and Xcode. How do I get the developer versions?

Comment: It looks like your dev program has expired. Are you sure it is active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select the 7.1 sdk beta tab. If you don't see it, your iOS dev program has probably expired (you have not renewed it for this year)

[image]